# What is the iterator type returned by this Rust function?

Tags: types, iterator, rust, type-inference, return-type

So I have this example code here:

```rust
use std::iter::Filter;
use std::slice::Iter;

fn main() {
    let numbers = vec![12i32, 26, 31, 56, 33, 16, 81];

    for number in ends_in_six(numbers) {
        println!("{}", number);
    }
}

fn ends_in_six(numbers: Vec<i32>) /* -> ??? */ {
    numbers.iter().filter(|&n| *n % 10 == 6)
}
```

I'm trying to return an iterator, which has always been pretty hairy in Rust from what I've gathered. Running the code [here](http://is.gd/Cyg9OO) gives me this error:

```rust
<anon>:13:5: 13:45 error: mismatched types:
 expected `()`,
    found `core::iter::Filter<core::slice::Iter<'_, i32>, [closure <anon>:13:27: 13:44]>`
(expected (),
    found struct `core::iter::Filter`) [E0308]
<anon>:13     numbers.iter().filter(|&n| *n % 10 == 6)
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Now, working off this (and based on my relatively limited knowledge of how this all works), it seems I should do something like:

```rust
fn ends_in_six<'a>(numbers: Vec<i32>) -> Filter<Iter<'a, i32>, /* ??? */> {
```

But now I'm stuck again, because I'm given `[closure <anon>:13:27: 13:44]` instead of an actual type. Even when I tried using the function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29168659/4728171) to try and find out the type, I was given:

```rust
core::iter::Filter<core::slice::Iter<i32>, [closure((&&i32,)) -> bool]>
```

So, trying to figure it out on my own, and basing it on the previous line, I attempted:

```rust
fn ends_in_six<'a>(numbers: Vec<i32>) -> Filter<Iter<'a, i32>, Fn(&&i32) -> bool> {
```

and got even more errors, because Fn is not constant at compile time (i.e. doesn't implement Sized). It makes sense, but I'm at a bit of a loss what else to try.

EDIT: I just [tried](http://is.gd/RGuIh0):

```rust
fn ends_in_six<'a, F>(numbers: Vec<i32>) -> Filter<Iter<'a, i32>, F>
  where F: Fn(&&i32) -> bool {
```

and now I'm getting these errors:

```rust
<anon>:7:19: 7:30 error: unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations required [E0282]
<anon>:7     for number in ends_in_six(numbers) {
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
<anon>:14:32: 14:34 error: the type of this value must be known in this context
<anon>:14     numbers.iter().filter(|&n| *n % 10 == 6)
                                         ^~
<anon>:14:27: 14:44 error: mismatched types:
 expected `F`,
    found `[closure <anon>:14:27: 14:44]`
(expected type parameter,
    found closure) [E0308]
<anon>:14     numbers.iter().filter(|&n| *n % 10 == 6)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: *"I'm trying to return an iterator, which has always been pretty hairy"* - it's not returning an iterator that is complicated, it's usually returning an iterator adapter that contains a closure. Or returning a non-concrete type that implements `Iterator`, which doesn't have a known size.

Comment: Returning an iterator containing a closure is easy, if you don't mind boxing: http://is.gd/nBad0O --- and once we get [`impl Trait` return types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/105), getting rid of the boxing is easy as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each closure has its own unique type (closures are sugar for a struct and a `Fn`, `FnMut` or `FnOnce` implementation, as determined) and there is no way of writing out the type of a closure.

One thing you can do is write it as a function and then cast it to a function pointer, as shown below.

Another thing is using boxed functions (`Box<Fn(&&i32) -> bool>`), like `Box::new(|&&n| n % 10 == 6)`. This involves a heap allocation and is in consequence not the most efficient, though in real life you don’t need to worry about the performance differences.

The generic attempt you made doesn’t work because generics are about allowing the *caller* to specify a type, any type, where in this case you want the *callee* to specify a single unique type.

```rust
use std::iter::Filter;
use std::slice::Iter;

fn main() {
    let numbers = vec![12i32, 26, 31, 56, 33, 16, 81];

    for number in ends_in_six(numbers) {
        println!("{}", number);
    }
}

fn ends_in_six(numbers: Vec<i32>) Filter<Iter<'a, i32>, fn(&&i32) -> bool> {
    fn filterer(&&n: &&i32) -> bool { n % 10 == 6 }
    numbers.iter().filter(filterer as fn(&&i32) -> bool)
}
```

Comment: The code at the end doesn't work and if I fix the trivial syntax errors, `numbers` does not live long enough, unsurprisingly. It's probably better to take a `&[i32]` instead of a `Vec<i32>`.

Comment: The explanation was helpful, and along with delnan's code solved my problem, so thanks.