# Concatenate a vector of vectors of strings

Tags: vector, concatenation, rust

I'm trying to write a function that receives a vector of vectors of strings and returns all vectors concatenated together, i.e. it returns a vector of strings.

The best I could do so far has been the following:

```
fn concat_vecs(vecs: Vec<Vec<String>>) -> Vec<String> {
    let vals : Vec<&String> = vecs.iter().flat_map(|x| x.into_iter()).collect();
    vals.into_iter().map(|v: &String| v.to_owned()).collect()
}
```

However, I'm not happy with this result, because it seems I should be able to get `Vec<String>` from the first `collect` call, but somehow I am not able to figure out how to do it.

I am even more interested to figure out *why* exactly the return type of `collect` is `Vec<&String>`. I tried to deduce this from the API documentation and the source code, but despite my best efforts, I couldn't even understand the signatures of functions.

So let me try and trace the types of each expression:

```
- vecs.iter(): Iter<T=Vec<String>, Item=Vec<String>>
- vecs.iter().flat_map(): FlatMap<I=Iter<Vec<String>>, U=???, F=FnMut(Vec<String>) -> U, Item=U>
- vecs.iter().flat_map().collect(): (B=??? : FromIterator<U>)
- vals was declared as Vec<&String>, therefore 
      vals == vecs.iter().flat_map().collect(): (B=Vec<&String> : FromIterator<U>). Therefore U=&String.
```

I'm assuming above that the type inferencer is able to figure out that `U=&String` based on the type of `vals`. But if I give the expression the explicit types in the code, this compiles without error:

```
fn concat_vecs(vecs: Vec<Vec<String>>) -> Vec<String> {
    let a: Iter<Vec<String>> = vecs.iter();
    let b: FlatMap<Iter<Vec<String>>, Iter<String>, _> = a.flat_map(|x| x.into_iter());
    let c = b.collect();
    print_type_of(&c);
    let vals : Vec<&String> = c;
    vals.into_iter().map(|v: &String| v.to_owned()).collect()
}
```

Clearly, `U=Iter<String>`... Please help me clear up this mess.

**EDIT:** thanks to bluss' hint, I was able to achieve one `collect` as follows:

```
fn concat_vecs(vecs: Vec<Vec<String>>) -> Vec<String> {
    vecs.into_iter().flat_map(|x| x.into_iter()).collect()
}
```

My understanding is that by using `into_iter` I transfer ownership of `vecs` to `IntoIter` and further down the call chain, which allows me to avoid copying the data inside the lambda call and therefore - magically - the type system gives me `Vec<String>` where it used to always give me `Vec<&String>` before. While it is certainly very cool to see how the high-level concept is reflected in the workings of the library, I wish I had any idea how this is achieved.

**EDIT 2:** After a laborious process of guesswork, looking at API docs and using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29168659/3646645) to decipher the types, I got them fully annotated (disregarding the lifetimes):

```
fn concat_vecs(vecs: Vec<Vec<String>>) -> Vec<String> {
    let a: Iter<Vec<String>> = vecs.iter();
    let f : &Fn(&Vec<String>) -> Iter<String> = &|x: &Vec<String>| x.into_iter();
    let b: FlatMap<Iter<Vec<String>>, Iter<String>, &Fn(&Vec<String>) -> Iter<String>> = a.flat_map(f);
    let vals : Vec<&String> = b.collect();
    vals.into_iter().map(|v: &String| v.to_owned()).collect()
}
```

Comment: `- vecs.iter(): Iter<T=Vec<String>, Item=Vec<String>>`: this is incorrect. There is no associated type named `Item` on struct `Iter` (only traits may have associated types). `vecs.iter()` is of type `Iter<Vec<String>>`, but [this type implements `Iterator<Item=&Vec<String>>`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/slice/struct.Iter.html#implementations) (note the `&`). When you `flat_map` this, you turn `&Vec<String>` into `&String`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd think about: why do you use iter() on the outer vec but into_iter() on the inner vecs? Using `into_iter()` is actually crucial, so that we don't have to copy first the inner vectors, then the strings inside, we just receive ownership of them.

We can actually write this just like a summation: concatenate the vectors two by two. Since we always reuse the allocation & contents of the same accumulation vector, this operation is linear time.

To minimize time spent growing and reallocating the vector, calculate the space needed up front.

```
fn concat_vecs(vecs: Vec<Vec<String>>) -> Vec<String> {
    let size = vecs.iter().fold(0, |a, b| a + b.len());
    vecs.into_iter().fold(Vec::with_capacity(size), |mut acc, v| {
        acc.extend(v); acc
    })
}
```

If you do want to clone all the contents, there's already a method for that, and you'd just use `vecs.concat() /* -> Vec<String> */`

---

The approach with `.flat_map` is fine, but if you don't want to clone the strings again you have to use `.into_iter()` on all levels: (`x` is `Vec<String>`).

`vecs.into_iter().flat_map(|x| x.into_iter()).collect()`

If instead you want to clone each string you can use this: (Changed `.into_iter()` to `.iter()` since `x` here is a `&Vec<String>` and both methods actually result in the same thing!)

`vecs.iter().flat_map(|x| x.iter().map(Clone::clone)).collect()`

Comment: This gives me some errors: `
    build.rs:104:9: 104:12 error: cannot borrow immutable local variable `acc` as mutable
    build.rs:104         acc.extend(v); v
                         ^~~
    note: in expansion of closure expansion
    build.rs:103:53: 105:6 note: expansion site
    build.rs:104:24: 104:25 error: use of moved value: `v` [E0382]
    build.rs:104         acc.extend(v); v`

Comment: maybe because I didn't test compile it until after I submitted, but then I fixed it

Comment: How can I independently learn about vecs.concat()? It's not on the API page for std::vec::Vec. I mean how am I supposed to find it if looking at the API doesn't give any hints? Even now that I empirically know it's there I can't figure out where it is defined.

Comment: As to your solution with fold(), thank you. Still, what I'm after is learning how to achieve the needed result independently, so I would really like to use my code as the starting point and see how it can be improved to only use one collect() rather than rewritten.

Comment: Well, this answers my main question, and I would really like to mark your answer as solution, but OTOH I also would like to get an answer to the meta-questions (how to figure out types by looking at the API). Perhaps my question is too broad?

Comment: The remark on `x.into_iter()` not being the method you think might be important

Comment: Instead of `flat_map(|x| x.into_iter())`, just do `flat_map(|x| x)`.

Comment: @kirillkh `concat` utilizes automatic dereferencing, so is actually a function on `*Vec<T>`, which is the slice `[T]`. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.concat

Comment: Thanks Veedrac. How would you go about finding `concat` if you didn't know it was there? I even tried to Google it with no luck.