# How to concatenate immutable vectors in one line?

Tags: vector, rust, concatenation

I have immutable vectors `a` and `b` where the elements are cheap to copy and I want to create a vector that forms the concatenation of these existing vectors without changing them (*).

[An earlier question addressed it if one of the vectors is mutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40792801/best-way-to-concatenate-vectors-in-rust), so an obvious answer is to first clone vector `a`, e.g.

```
let mut r = a.clone();
r.extend(&b);
```

but that seems neither elegant nor efficient (extending can easily cause one needless reallocation, right?). The [(corrected) best alternative I (being a Rust noob) come up with](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=041b73f03a67d9fa69dadffb2c4f488e) is:

```
fn cat(a: &Vec<i32>, b: &Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut r = Vec::<i32>::with_capacity(a.len() + b.len());
    r.extend(a);
    r.extend(b);
    r
}
```

Since these elements are cheap to copy, the answer to the [more generic question for vectors of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126048/concatenate-a-vector-of-vectors-of-strings) should apply here, but `vec![a, b].concat()` only seems to work if you construct the vector of vectors by moving the vectors into it, because `vec![&a, &b].concat()`yields "no method named `concat` found".

Is there a one-liner for this seemingly simple job, even if it's not optimal?

----------
(*) turns out there are two meanings to "without changing":

- Just immutable, which in Rust means that if code compiles, it will not see the variable with a changed value; but the variable's value may be moved out, and future code cannot use the variable anymore.
- Actually read-only, leaving the variable untouched for further or future code; this is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`concat`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.concat) does work, if used correctly:

```
fn cat(a: &[i32], b: &[i32]) -> Vec<i32> {
    [a, b].concat()
}

fn main() {
    let a = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let b = vec![7, 8, 9];
    println!("{:?}", cat(&a, &b));
}
```

Comment: From my outsider point of view, this still mutates `a` and `b`: it moves them, making them unusable further in the code or in further iterations. But I'm beginning to see the term immutable I stuck on the question doesn't mean untouchable in Rust, and doesn't have to. So this looks like the most elegant way to concatenate immutable vectors in my mind.

Comment: @Stein It doesn't move them. `cat` accepts two slices. You can use `a` and `b` further in `main`. What do you mean by *"untouchable"*?

Comment: You're right, I can simply [turn your code into an iteration](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=6ec3e82349560e4eee90702724309f4a). But not if I [try to avoid the intermediate function](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=6431e07d2c39aa55d6fe937be8d64429). I'll try to understand that later.

Comment: @Stein Look at the [revisions of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53476705/revisions) (#1) and then you may be able to get your "intermediate" function work. Report please :)

Comment: Thanks, I got it now. An actual one-liner is `[a.as_slice(), b.as_slice()].concat()` and the function invocation does the slicy thing implicitly.

Comment: I tried to clartify _untouchable_ (read-only? radical immutability?) versus immutable in the question. Is there an official word it? Something not declared as const but treated as const?

Answer (score 5):

Arrays can `concat()` slices to a vector, you just need to give a stronger hint to the compiler:

```rust
let combined = [a.as_slice(), b.as_slice()].concat();
```

Here's a [rust playground to try it out](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=dc7fcb9c5bc32a4db493f68577785076). You can see that neither `a` nor `b` are consumed, and `combined` is a new vector. Note that this fails if you try the `&` shorthand for borrowing instead of specifying `as_slice()`.

Answer (score 3):

> Editor's note: The OP changed their question after this answer was provided. Refer to the [version of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53469274/3) this answer was created from.

Your first example doesn't really make sense. You mention immutability, but since you are transferring ownership of the vectors to the `cat` function, it can choose what the mutability is of the variables. In this case, you might as well just reuse the allocation of one of them:

```
fn cat(mut a: Vec<i32>, b: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    a.extend(b);
    a
}
```

> extending can easily cause needless reallocation

This is technically possible, but **extremely unlikely**. There's a reason that iterators have the method [`size_hint`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.size_hint) — this allows collections to allocate exactly whenever possible.

> a one-liner

```
a.into_iter().chain(b).collect::<Vec<_>>()
```

This destroys the allocation of the vectors `a` and `b` (not of the elements inside them) and creates a new allocation to hold all the items.

---

If you had immutable *slices*, you can use the same technique:

```
fn cat<T: Clone>(a: &[T], b: &[T]) -> Vec<T> {
    a.iter().chain(b).cloned().collect()
}
```

See also:

- [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec) or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)

Comment: "extending can easily cause needless reallocation" This is technically possible, but extremely unlikely: I don't mean that during extending it reallocates more than once, just that after the clone it didn't even know about the second part that is going to be appended.

Comment: My initial example code was a botched attempt to formalize the problem described, so the first part of the answer doesn't apply (some of it belongs with the first linked question instead.)