# Using rustc_serialize and getting unquoted strings

Tags: rust

So I have gone through 90% of the tutorial on Rust and I think I mostly have a grasp on the syntax. I'm attempting to start writing code with it I'm currently using the `rustc_serialize` library to parse JSON from `stdin` and I'm not getting the results I expect. I have the following JSON file called `message.txt` the following content:

```
{"text": "hello world"}
```

Here is the Rust code to accept `stdin` and parse out the `text` field:

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;

use std::io::{self, Read};
use rustc_serialize::json::Json;

fn main() {
    // provide a buffer for stdin
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    let _ = io::stdin().read_to_string(&mut buffer);

    // parse the json
    let message = match Json::from_str(&mut buffer) {
        Ok(m) => m,
        Err(_) => panic!("Stdin provided invalid JSON")
    };

    // get the message object and "text" field string
    let message_object = message.as_object().unwrap();
    let message_string = message_object.get("text").unwrap();

    println!("{}", message_string);
    println!("{}", &message_string.to_string()[0..4]);
}
```

The following code outputs:

```
"Hello World"
"Hel
```

I'm currently outputting the byte slice to make sure the quote wasn't something that was added by print. According to the docs `message_string` shouldn't have quotes around it.

If I print out the data using the example from the documentation then it prints the value of "text" without quotes:

```
for (key, value) in message_object.iter() {
    println!("{}: {}", key, match *value {
        Json::U64(v) => format!("{} (u64)", v),
        Json::String(ref v) => format!("{} (string)", v),
        _ => format!("other")
    });
}
```

Output:

```
text: hello world (string)
```

I'm a newbie to Rust so I probably just don't understand the string manipulation parts of Rust all that well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `message_string` isn't what you think it is. I discovered that when I tried to use `len` on the "string", which didn't work (I assume that's why you have a `to_string` when you are slicing). Let's [make the compiler tell us what it is](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21747136/155423):

```
let () = message_string;
```

Has the error:

```
error: mismatched types:
 expected `&rustc_serialize::json::Json`,
    found `()`
```

It's a [`Json`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc-serialize/rustc_serialize/json/enum.Json.html)! We need to convert that enumerated type into a string-like thing:

```
let message_object = message.as_object().unwrap();
let message_json = message_object.get("text").unwrap();
let message_string = message_json.as_string().unwrap();
```

Ultimately, I'd argue that [`Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) (which allows the `{}` format string) should **not** have been implemented for this type, as `Display` means format in an end-user-focused manner. It's probably too late to change that decision now though.

---

I know that `unwrap` is great for quick prototyping, but I'd be remiss in not showing a slightly more idiomatic way of doing this:

```
fn main() {
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_to_string(&mut buffer).expect("Could not read from stdin");

    let message = Json::from_str(&mut buffer).expect("Stdin provided invalid JSON");

    let message_string = message.as_object().and_then(|obj| {
        obj.get("text").and_then(|json| {
            json.as_string()
        })
    }).expect("The `text` key was missing or not a string");

    println!("{}", message_string);
}
```

Ignoring the `Result` from `read_to_string` is worse than panicking. ^_^

Comment: `let () =` trick is great, this is probably well-known but I am starting in Rust as well, and this is handy.

Comment: `let () =` is an amazing trick! Thank you! Also, really appreciate the idiomatic syntax and the great explanation. When you say `Display` do mean [this trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html)?

Comment: @glenbot yup. I've edited that link into my answer too. :-)