# Mismatched types when building a std::process::Command in a loop

Tags: rust, command-line-arguments

I'm new to Rust, trying to learn safe programming by working with the borrow checker. One thing I tried was to construct a [`std::process::Command`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html) based on input.

If I just wanted to do what all the examples in the documentation assume I want to do and just run a command with arguments that I know at coding time, it works fine:

```
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let mut command = Command::new("/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator")
                              .arg("-e")
                              .arg("editor")
                              .output()
                              .unwrap();
}
```

I'm trying to run a command that I build at runtime. In order to do this, I need to separate the construction of the `Command` struct from the building of its arguments. When I do it this way, the compiler complains about mismatched types:

```
use std::env::args;
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let args = args().collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let mut command = Command::new("/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator");

    for arg in &args[1..args.len()] {
        command = command.arg(arg);
    }
}
```

The error I get is

> mismatched types: expected `std::process::Command`, found `&mut std::process::Command`

Looking at the documentation for [`std::process::Command::arg`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.arg), it says that it expects a `&mut self` and returns a `&mut Command`. According to the compiler, that's exactly what it's getting. Is the documentation wrong, or (far more likely) am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: Note that `&args[1..args.len()]` can just be written as `&args[1..]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we check out the full error provided by the compiler, that may help shed light:

```
error: mismatched types:
 expected `std::process::Command`,
    found `&mut std::process::Command`
(expected struct `std::process::Command`,
    found &-ptr) [E0308]

command = command.arg(arg);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The compiler is pointing to the entire right hand side of the expression. This indicates that something is wrong with the *return value* of the `arg` call. Let's check out the [documentation for `arg`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.arg):

```
fn arg<S: AsRef<OsStr>>(&mut self, arg: S) -> &mut Command
```

So, `arg` operates on a mutable reference to `self`, accepts an `arg` parameter, and *returns* a mutable reference to itself. Let's change your code a bit to test our hypothesis. We will use a trick to [make the compiler tell us the types of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21747136/155423):

```
for arg in &args[1..args.len()] {
    let _: () = command;
    let _: () = command.arg(arg);
}
```

This yields the errors:

```
error: mismatched types:
 expected `()`,
    found `std::process::Command`

let _: () = command;
            ^~~~~~~

error: mismatched types:
 expected `()`,
    found `&mut std::process::Command`

let _: () = command.arg(arg);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Hah, we got it! We are trying to store a `&mut Command` into a variable of type `Command`. Not gonna work! Since this instance of the builder pattern mutates the builder, we don't have to do anything special to preserve it:

```
use std::env;
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let mut command = Command::new("/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator");

    for arg in env::args().skip(1) {
        command.arg(arg);
    }
}
```

---

There is another style of the builder pattern that accepts `self` by value and the returns it by value. In that case, you **would** have to keep track of the builder between each step, and your code would have worked as-is.

Comment: That explains it, thank you. I also learned several new things: args.len() is optional in a slice, skip(1), how to make the compiler tell us the types, and the purpose of the tildes in the error messages. Awesome!