# Cannot borrow immutable borrowed content as mutable

Tags: rust

I'm trying to develop a message routing app. I've read the official Rust docs and some articles and thought that I got how pointers, owning, and borrowing stuff works but realized that I didn't.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::vec::Vec;

struct Component {
    address: &'static str,
    available_workers: i32,
    lang: i32
}

struct Components {
    data: HashMap<i32, Vec<Component>>
}

impl Components {
    fn new() -> Components {
        Components {data: HashMap::new() }
    }

    fn addOrUpdate(&mut self, component: Component) -> &Components {
        if !self.data.contains_key(&component.lang) {

            self.data.insert(component.lang, vec![component]);
        } else {
            let mut q = self.data.get(&component.lang); // this extra line is required because of the error: borrowed value does not live long enough
            let mut queue = q.as_mut().unwrap();
            queue.remove(0);
            queue.push(component);
        }
        self
    }

}
```

(Also available on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8cd9bda8afba5dbb3d239214692302e0&version=stable))

Produces the error:

```
error: cannot borrow immutable borrowed content `**queue` as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:26:13
   |
26 |             queue.remove(0);
   |             ^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable

error: cannot borrow immutable borrowed content `**queue` as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:27:13
   |
27 |             queue.push(component);
   |             ^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

Could you please explain the error and it would be great if you can give me the right implementation.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here is an [MCVE](/help/mcve) of your problem:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Components {
    data: HashMap<u8, Vec<u8>>,
}

impl Components {
    fn add_or_update(&mut self, component: u8) {
        let mut q = self.data.get(&component);
        let mut queue = q.as_mut().unwrap();
        queue.remove(0);
    }
}
```

**Before NLL**

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow immutable borrowed content `**queue` as mutable
  --> src/lib.rs:11:9
   |
11 |         queue.remove(0);
   |         ^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

**After NLL**

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `**queue` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
  --> src/lib.rs:11:9
   |
11 |         queue.remove(0);
   |         ^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

Many times, when something seems surprising like this, it's useful to [print out the types involved](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21747136/155423). Let's print out the type of `queue`:

```
let mut queue: () = q.as_mut().unwrap();
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:10:29
   |
10 |         let mut queue: () = q.as_mut().unwrap();
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected (), found mutable reference
   |
   = note: expected type `()`
              found type `&mut &std::vec::Vec<u8>`
```

We have a *mutable* reference to an *immutable* reference to a `Vec<u8>`. Because we have an immutable reference to the `Vec`, we cannot modify it! Changing `self.data.get` to `self.data.get_mut` changes the type to `&mut &mut collections::vec::Vec<u8>` and the code compiles.

---

If you want to implement the concept of "insert or update", you should check into the [`entry` API](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry), which is more efficient and concise.

Beyond that, Rust uses `snake_case` for method naming, not `camelCase`.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand it better. Thanks for advice about printing types, it turns out very helpful for troubleshooting

Comment: Is the link under *print out the types involved* still available? There is a SO questions, but I thought the link pointed to some answer.

Comment: @stej the link is to the question. That allows a better answer to come in or for the implementer to pick a different answer if the situation is different. In this case I used the "assign to the empty tuple" version.