# How to create a Rust struct with an image::ImageBuffer as a member?

Tags: struct, rust

I'm using the [image](http://www.piston.rs/image/image/index.html) crate for picture manipulation and want to create a little wrapper to make my code a bit fancier.

```
extern crate image;

const BLACK: [u8; 4] = [0, 0, 0, 255];
const WHITE: [u8; 4] = [255, 255, 255, 255];
const RED: [u8; 4] = [255, 0, 0, 255];

pub struct Picture {
    buffer: image::ImageBuffer,
    width: u32,
    height: u32
}

impl Picture {
    // My functions like fill(), line() etc.
}
```

But when I compile this, I have an error:

```
src\pic.rs:11:13: 11:31 error: wrong number of type arguments: expected 2, found 0 [E0243]
src\pic.rs:11     buffer: image::ImageBuffer,
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

In the source, I saw that `ImageBuffer` accepts two arguments:

```
pub struct ImageBuffer<P: Pixel, Container> {
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
    _phantom: PhantomData<P>,
    data: Container,
}
```

So I decided to put those arguments in the `Picture` declaration:

```
pub struct Picture {
    buffer: image::ImageBuffer<image::Pixel>,
}
```

And got another error:

```
src\pic.rs:11:32: 11:44 error: the value of the associated type `Subpixel` (from the trait `pic::image::buffer::Pixel`) must be specified [E0191]
src\pic.rs:11     buffer: image::ImageBuffer<image::Pixel>,
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

That means I must specify some value for the `Subpixel` type, and I don't get it. I don't know how to declare that `Container` type, I can't find anything useful in the sources. I tried to re-read the Rust Book, examples, `rustc --explain E0191` but I am still lost.

update:

In sources found next declaration:

```
impl<P, Container> ImageBuffer<P, Container>
where P: Pixel + 'static,
      P::Subpixel: 'static,
      Container: Deref<Target=[P::Subpixel]>
```

And `Subpixel` is:

```
/// Primitive trait from old stdlib
pub trait Primitive: Copy + NumCast + Num + PartialOrd<Self> + Clone + Bounded {
}
```

But it not public for my crate.

Comment: http://www.piston.rs/image/image/type.RgbaImage.html

Comment: @starblue, thanks, now I see :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation for `ImageBuffer`](http://www.piston.rs/image/image/struct.ImageBuffer.html), we can see the trait requirements for the type parameters:

```
impl<P, Container> ImageBuffer<P, Container>
    where P: Pixel + 'static,
          P::Subpixel: 'static,
          Container: Deref<Target=[P::Subpixel]>
```

So, it's important that the second type parameter can dereference to a slice of subpixels. `Subpixel` is determined by the [`Pixel` trait](http://www.piston.rs/image/image/trait.Pixel.html), which has a few implementations:

- `Rgb<T>`
- `Luma<T>`
- `Rgba<T>`
- `LumaA<T>`

Where `T` is the subpixel type.

This is all pretty complicated, but should provide a good bit of power and generality.

Note that I've only shown *one* of the implementation blocks. There are others that require `DerefMut` or that require the subpixel to be a `u8`.

---

How do you actually use it? First you need to pick a specific color and subpixel type. Based on your colors, it looks like you want to use a 4-channel, 8-bit color type. That would be [`Rgba<u8>`](http://www.piston.rs/image/image/struct.Rgba.html).

There are many types that could dereference to an `&[u8]` or `&mut [u8]`. The obvious (but not only!) choice would be a `Vec<u8>`.

Combining these two, your structure needs to be something like:

```
buffer: image::ImageBuffer<Rgba<u8>, Vec<u8>>,
```

Then, it's just a matter of creating the structure and doing things to it:

```
extern crate image;

use image::{ImageBuffer, Pixel, Rgba};

pub struct Picture {
    buffer: ImageBuffer<Rgba<u8>, Vec<u8>>,
}

impl Picture {
    fn new(width: u32, height: u32) -> Self {
        // There's probably a cleaner way to figure out the right size
        let storage = vec![0; 4 * width as usize * height as usize];
        let buf = ImageBuffer::from_raw(width, height, storage).unwrap();

        Picture {
            buffer: buf,
        }
    }

    fn fill_red(&mut self) {
        let color = Rgba::from_channels(255, 0, 0, 255);

        for p in self.buffer.pixels_mut() {
            *p = color;
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut pic = Picture::new(256, 256);
    pic.fill_red();
}
```

Note that `ImageBuffer` already tracks the width and height, so there's no real reason to track them a second time.

---

However, all of this is the hard way. There are convenience functions like `new` which will allocate storage for you:

```
buffer: ImageBuffer::new(width, height),
```

These functions are hard-coded to return a `Vec` as the `Container`. If you didn't see that in the docs, you could try something like [printing the type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21747136/155423):

```
let () = ImageBuffer::new(width, height);
```

Which would tell you the type in the error message:

```
expected `image::buffer::ImageBuffer<_, collections::vec::Vec<_>>`,
```

Comment: Now I can see the light! Thanks, it's really improves my understanding. Oh, and "printing the type" trick is funny.