# How do I know what types I have to put into the generic type parameters?

Tags: rust

I'm learning Rust by looking at and manipulating examples from others. I tried to encapsulate the following code into a struct:

```
let mut encoder: gfx::Encoder<_, _> = factory.create_command_buffer().into();
```

I want to create a struct like this:

```
pub struct Window {
    encoder: gfx::Encoder<?, ?>,
    // ...
}
```

How do I know what types I have to put into the question marks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the type of your variable (`encoder`) to cause a type mismatch. The easiest type to use for this is `()`:

```
let mut encoder: gfx::Encoder<(), ()> = factory.create_command_buffer().into();
```

This will generate an error with the concrete types, which you can then clean up and use directly.

See also [How do I print the type of a variable in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21747136/155423).

---

In many cases, you'd use something a bit simpler:

```
let mut encoder: () = factory.create_command_buffer().into();
```

But that's unlikely to work in this *specific* case because `into` has a polymorphic return type. It needs to have some concrete type specified in order to know which implementation should be called.