# Does &mut do anything when declaring a for loop variable?

Tags: rust

Consider the following (dumb) program:

```
fn main() {
    let mut array = &mut [1u8, 2u8, 3u8];
    for &mut value in array {
    }
}
```

It compiles and runs okay (though warns about unused variables/unnecessary mutability, as expected). But what does `&mut` do in the `for` statement?

It doesn't seem to give you a mutable reference into the array, since trying to assign `value = 0;` results in the error:

```
error[E0384]: re-assignment of immutable variable `value`
```

Is `&mut` here a no-op then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So there's a few different things that's going on here. First, here's the answer:

```
fn main() {
    let mut array = [1u8, 2u8, 3u8];
    for value in &mut array {
        *value = 0; 
   }
}
```

So. Where did you go wrong? Let's look at what `value` is, like this:

```
for &mut value in array {
    let () = value;
}
```

This gives this error:

```
  = note: expected type `u8`
  = note:    found type `()`
```

So here, `value` is a `u8`. But why? Well, let's try this one:

```
for value in array {
    let () = value;
}
```

This gives:

```
  = note: expected type `&mut u8`
  = note:    found type `()`
```

So, `value` here is an `&mut u8`, a reference into the array. So by saying `for &mut value`, we're saying "hey, this is going to be a mutable pointer to a `u8`. We'd like `value` to be the `u8` value that's pointed at. This is because `&mut value` is a *pattern*, which binds against a `&mut T` and binds `value` to the `T`.

So, we remove the `&mut`, since we don't want a copy of the value, we want to use it to modify what's pointed to. So that looks like this:

```
fn main() {
    let mut array = &mut [1u8, 2u8, 3u8];
    for value in array {
        *value = 0;
    }
}
```

This... compiles! Are we done? Well, let's try to print out `array`, just to be sure:

```
fn main() {
    let mut array = &mut [1u8, 2u8, 3u8];
    for value in array {
        *value = 0;
    }

    println!("{:?}", array);
}
```

This fails to compile:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `array`
 --> <anon>:7:22
  |
3 |     for value in array {
  |                  ----- value moved here
```

We've destroyed `array` by iterating. Why's that? Well, when you loop over an array like this, you're saying you want to loop by owner. But that's *not* actually what we want; we want to loop by mutable reference.

Arrays have a method to help with this:

```
fn main() {
    let mut array = &mut [1u8, 2u8, 3u8];
    for value in array.iter_mut() {
        *value = 0;
    }

    println!("{:?}", array);
}
```

`iter_mut` will iterate by `&mut T` rather than by `T`. So this works!

One last thing, though:

```
let mut array = &mut [1u8, 2u8, 3u8];
```

This says that `array` is a `&mut [u8; 3]`, that is, a mutable reference to an array, not an array itself. This probably isn't what you actually want, and it's not neccesary with our code. So we can remove the `&mut` bit:

```
let mut array = [1u8, 2u8, 3u8];
```

And now you're at our first code sample.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a *fantastic* answer. Thank you for the thorough explanation and all the examples!

Answer (score 1):

> Is `&mut` here a no-op then?

No, it's part of a pattern. [Print the type of `value`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21747136/155423):

```
fn main() {
    let mut array = &mut [1u8, 2u8, 3u8];

    for &mut value in array {
        let () = value;
        // expected type `u8`
    }

    for value in array {
        let () = value;
        // expected type `&mut u8`
    }
}
```

Comment: Desugaring the `for`-loop into its `loop { match ... {} }` equivalent and thinking of the pattern matching involved there makes the results make sense. Thanks! Earlier I tried printing the type (with the `let () = value;` trick) but was confused that it was a `u8`, but that's because I was expecting `&mut value` to declare a mutable reference rather than act as a pattern. Thanks for the concise example and explanation!