# Rust Type Inference Error

Tags: rust, type-inference

I'm writing a chat server over TCP as a learning project. I've been tinkering with the [ws](https://crates.io/crates/ws) crate today, but I've come across an issue. This is the code I wrote, modifying their [server example](https://github.com/housleyjk/ws-rs/blob/master/examples/server.rs).

```
extern crate ws;
extern crate env_logger;

use ws::listen;

fn main() {
    // Setup logging
    env_logger::init().unwrap();

    // Listen on an address and call the closure for each connection
    if let Err(error) = listen("127.0.0.1:3012", |out| {
        let mut message: String;
        // The handler needs to take ownership of out, so we use move
        move |message| {
            message = message.trim();
            // Handle messages received on this connection
            println!("Server got message '{}'. ", message);

            // Use the out channel to send messages back
            out.send(message)
        }

    }) {
        // Inform the user of failure
        println!("Failed to create WebSocket due to {:?}", error);
    }
}
```

When I try compiling it I get an error:

```
error: the type of this value must be known in this context
  --> src/main.rs:15:23
   |
15 |             message = message.trim();
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Why is this happening? How may I fix this?

Comment: In the future, you will be well-served by [printing out the type of a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21747136/155423).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`move |message|` shadows the `message` variable you've declared outside the closure. So within the closure.. `message` is said to be a `ws::Message` ... except you've done this:

```
message = message.trim();
```

The compiler goes "oh no! `trim()`? That doesn't exist for `ws::Message`".. and so now it doesn't quite know what to do.

#### Option 1

The first fix involves delegating the `trim()` call to the client who sends the message.

The fix is to not make any assumptions about what the message is inside this closure. If you keep this:

```
move |message|
```

..but remove the `trim()` call, the compiler happily infers its type as `ws::Message` and will build:

```
if let Err(error) = listen("127.0.0.1:3012", |out| {
    // The handler needs to take ownership of out, so we use move
    move |message| {
        // --- REMOVED trim() call ---

        // Handle messages received on this connection
        println!("Server got message '{}'. ", message);

        // Use the out channel to send messages back
        out.send(message)
    }
}
```

This gives you the option of delegating the `trim()` call to the client instead.

#### Option 2

Option 2 involves inspecting the type of message you've received, and making sure you trim it only if it is text:

```
// The handler needs to take ownership of out, so we use move
move |mut message: ws::Message| {
    // Only do it if the Message is text
    if message.is_text() {
        message = ws::Message::Text(message.as_text().unwrap().trim().into());
    }

    // Handle messages received on this connection
    println!("Server got message '{}'. ", message);

    // Use the out channel to send messages back
    out.send(message)
}
```

This is perhaps a little more verbose than it needs to be.. but hopefully it shows you what the actual issue is with your original snippet of code.

Comment: Awesome answer! Thank you!