# Re-assignment of immutable variable that should be a mutable borrow in a loop

Tags: rust, mutable

I am trying to modify a mutable `sums: Vec<i64>` while iterating over it. The loop code is as follows:

```
for (j, &mut sum) in sums.iter_mut().enumerate() {
    if !(j == i) {
        sum += n;
    }
}
```

And here is the error I get:

```
error[E0384]: re-assignment of immutable variable `sum`
  --> mini_max_sum.rs:27:17
   |
25 |         for (j, &mut sum) in sums.iter_mut().enumerate() {
   |                      --- first assignment to `sum`
26 |             if !(j == i) {
27 |                 sum += n;
   |                 ^^^^^^^^ re-assignment of immutable variable
```

This seems totally arcane to me. Rust lets me mutably borrow `sum` from `sums`, but the compiler prevents me from actually modifying it. Omitting `.enumerate()` does not even alter the resulting error code.

I would like to know how to fix the loop.

Comment: FYI, `!(j == i)` would normally be written as `j != i`.

Comment: Maybe you want this ? https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2f7b96cfd423fbf8586608388c68ba0e&version=stable&backtrace=0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why you decided to add `&mut` to the pattern for the loop variable, but that's the problem. You need to take the mutable reference directly and then dereference it when you increment it:

```
fn main() {
    let mut sums = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let i = 0;
    let n = 0;

    for (j, sum) in sums.iter_mut().enumerate() {
        if j != i {
            *sum += n;
        }
    }
}
```

With `&mut` in the pattern, you are actually destructuring the variable and removing the mutable reference. If you [print the type of your `sum` variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21747136/155423), you'll see that it's an `i64`.

Comment: I didn't get it. What exactly is wrong with `&mut sum`? That seems to make more sense to me. Even I wrote that ending up with the same error. Now when you write just `sum`, that makes it immutable and copied, right? I want the reference to the object so that I can modify it, so I wrote `&mut sum`. Please explain why is that wrong?

Comment: @Nawaz In a pattern, the structure that is matched is removed. For example, in `Some(foo)` the `Some` wrapper is removed, leaving `foo` bound to the value inside. The same happens with `&` or `&mut` in a pattern.