# How to create a boxed slice without using type ascription?

Tags: rust

It is easy to create a boxed slice:

```
fn main() {
    let _ = Box::new([42, 0]);
}
```

But if I want to add specify a type:

```
fn main() {
    let _ = Box::<[i32]>::new([42, 0]);
}
```

I get:

```
error: no associated item named `new` found for type `std::boxed::Box<[i32]>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:2:13
   |
 2 |     let _ = Box::<[i32]>::new([42, 0]);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `new` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied: `[i32] : std::marker::Sized`
```

This is really strange, because it works with type ascription:

```
fn main() {
    let _: Box<[i32]> = Box::new([42, 0]);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It is easy to create a boxed slice

Except you didn't do that. If you [print the type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21747136/155423), you can see that `Box::new([1, 2])` creates a *boxed array*, not a slice. On the other hand, `let _: Box<[i32]> = Box::new([1, 2])` creates a boxed array and the converts it to a *boxed slice*. These have different types. Notably, the first type has a length known at compile time, the second no longer does.

You can use `as` as well:

```
fn main() {
    let _ = Box::new([1, 2]) as Box<[i32]>;
}
```

`Box::<[i32]>::new([1, 2])` doesn't work for the reason the error message says: `T` is not `Sized`. `T` is directly mapped to the type being boxed.

`Box::new([1, 2]) as Box<[i32]>` works because a sized item is passed to `Box::new` and then it is converted to a type with an unsized inner bit using [unsized coercions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/coercions.html).

It appears that unsized coercions don't apply for [*actual* type ascription](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0803-type-ascription.md), an unstable feature in nightly Rust:

```
#![feature(type_ascription)]

fn main() {
    let foo = Box::new([1, 2]): Box<[i32]>;
}
```

---

For this *specific* case, you can use `into_boxed_slice`, which should avoid the need for any stack allocation.

```
vec![1, 2].into_boxed_slice();
```

Comment: Is `::<Type>::` not type ascription?

Comment: @Boiethios no, that's a separate feature that is not stabilized.

Comment: About the last line, I tried to use the opposite: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.into_vec with an empty slice, *e.g.*: `Box::<[i32]>::new([]).into_vec()`

Comment: Just a terminological point: it seems to be an unsizing coercion and not a `Deref` coercion.

Comment: @MasakiHara thank you! I always screw up the various coercions.

Comment: @Shepmaster, `as` casts are [superset of coercions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/casts.html) and `Box<[T; N]>` can be coerced to `Box<[T]>` because `[T; N]` is `Unsize<[T]>` ([Unsize trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Unsize.html)) and there exists blanket implementation [`impl<T: Unsize<U>, U> CoerceUnsized<Box<U>> for Box<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.CoerceUnsized.html)

Comment: Anyway, for now it can be described as compiler magic. [DST coercion RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0982-dst-coercion.md) isn't stable yet.

Answer (score 2):

This is an [experimental feature](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23416):

```
#![feature(type_ascription)]

fn main() {
    let _ = Box::new([42, 0]: [i32; 2]);
}
```

Also, in that case you need to be explicit about the length.

Comment: I was going to answer similarly, but OP is likely just misusing the term "type ascription". They really just mean to use a turbofish. They also want to have a `Box<[i32]>`, not a `Box<[i32; 2]>` — these are different types.

Comment: @Shepmaster in that case I don't know if it's possible :) - especially if you want a boxed slice without a specific length.

Comment: Hum, I think I understand now from your comments.