# Why do I need to dereference HashMap's key twice?

Tags: hashmap, rust, dereference

I've only been learning Rust for a few days. I think that these two code samples are the same, but the compiler disagrees. Can you explain what happens in part II? Why do I need to dereference `key` twice, but `value` once?

**Part I**

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

let mut h = HashMap::new();   
h.insert(1, 1);
h.insert(2, 2);

let mut keys: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
let mut values: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();

for (k, v) in &h {
    keys.push(**k);
    values.push(*v);
}
```

**Part II**

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3, 8, 6, 3, 1, 4, 6, 7];

    use std::collections::HashMap;

    let mut h = HashMap::new();

    for element in &v {
        let count = h.entry(element).or_insert(0);

        *count += 1;
    }

    let mut keys: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
    let mut values: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();

    for (k, v) in &h {
        keys.push(**k);
        values.push(*v);
    }

    println!("{:?}", keys);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you didn't specify the type of your `HashMap`, the compiler inferred it.

```
let v = vec![1i32, 2, 3];
let mut h = HashMap::new();
for i in &v {
    h.insert(i, ());
}
```

The type of `h` here is `HashMap<&i32, ()>`, and the type of `i` is `&i32`. Why does `i` have the type `&i32`? Because that's how `IntoIterator` on `&Vec` is implemented. In general, when you iterate over a reference, you get references.

If you want a `HashMap` with a key type that isn't a reference, you can say so. Then you'll get a different error message when you attempt to insert the reference.

```
let v = vec![1i32, 2, 3];
let mut h: HashMap<i32, ()> = HashMap::new();
for i in &v {
    h.insert(i, ());
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:6:18
  |
6 |         h.insert(i, ());
  |                  ^ expected i32, found &i32
  |
  = note: expected type `i32`
             found type `&i32`
```

And then you can replace the key to be inserted with `*i`.

Answer (score 4):

The full type of your `HashMap` is inferred as `HashMap<&i32, i32>`. This can be verified by [using the following trick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21747136/155423):

```
let () = h;
```

to trigger a type error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:17:9
   |
17 |     let () = h;
   |         ^^ expected struct `std::collections::HashMap`, found ()
   |
   = note: expected type `std::collections::HashMap<&{integer}, {integer}>`
              found type `()`
```

(at this point the compiler was not yet sure the final type will be `HashMap<&i32, i32>`, hence the `{integer}`s in the type signature)

When you are iterating over `&h`, the `(k, v)` tuple has type `(&&i32, &i32)` (which can also be confirmed with the aforementioned trick), which is why you need a double dereference for `k` and only one for `v`.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to dereference once

Here's an [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3ea366fb2e5ca98429e82ac22094e7ad&version=stable) of your code working

Comment: Could you see my supplement?