# Why is Rust's assert_eq! implemented using a match?

Tags: rust

Here's Rust's [`assert_eq!` macro implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.23.0/src/libcore/macros.rs#L109-L138). I've copied only the first branch for brevity:

```
macro_rules! assert_eq {
    ($left:expr, $right:expr) => ({
        match (&$left, &$right) {
            (left_val, right_val) => {
                if !(*left_val == *right_val) {
                    panic!(r#"assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `{:?}`,
 right: `{:?}`"#, left_val, right_val)
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

What's the purpose of the `match` here? Why isn't checking for non-equality enough?

Comment: Looks like it's evaluating the expressions.

Comment: The principal motivator seems to be to extend the lifetime of temporary values created in the match statement to make assert_eq! more useful, see this commit: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/d3c831ba4a4 - I'm not answering since I can't explain why this works (yet). See this playground link for experiments: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3e103c5eac005189947a868cd9ec5174&version=stable

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Alright, let's remove the match.

```
    macro_rules! assert_eq_2 {
        ($left:expr, $right:expr) => ({
            if !($left == $right) {
                panic!(r#"assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `{:?}`,
 right: `{:?}`"#, $left, $right)
            }
        });
    }
```

Now, let's pick a completely random example...

```
fn really_complex_fn() -> i32 {
    // Hit the disk, send some network requests,
    // and mine some bitcoin, then...
    return 1;
}

assert_eq_2!(really_complex_fn(), 1);
```

This would expand to...

```
{
    if !(really_complex_fn() == 1) {
        panic!(r#"assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `{:?}`,
 right: `{:?}`"#, really_complex_fn(), 1)
    }
}
```

As you can see, we're calling the function *twice*.  That's less than ideal, even more so if the result of the function could change each time it's called.

The `match` is just a quick, easy way to evaluate both "arguments" to the macro exactly once and bind them to variable names.

Comment: Wouldn't this be possible with something like `let left = $left;`?

Comment: @JeroenBollen There is a slight difference between that and a match which crops up in edge cases, but I don't recall the details.  I *think* it has something to do with the exact lifetime of the temporaries.  Since I don't know, I avoided mentioning it.

Comment: Indeed, `match expr { x => {...} }` is the Rust equivalent of `let x = expr in ...`, in that it's the most relaxed with respect to lifetime temporaries and "should always work", e.g. `match e { x => f(x) }` should be always equivalent to `f(e)`.  

On the other hand, `let x = expr;` is more "imperative" and doesn't allow keeping nested temporaries around, e.g. `let x = f(&g());` only compiles if `f` uses its reference argument without returning it, as the temporary it points to only lives for the duration of the call.

Comment: I couldn't find it before, but this is one of the blog posts about lifetimes of temporaries (note that it might not entirely reflect current Rust): http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2014/01/09/rvalue-lifetimes-in-rust/

Comment: Aside: the code is formatted the way it is because it's the middle of a multi-line raw string literal with embedded leading spaces.  Indenting the text changes how it prints.

Answer (score 14):

Using `match` ensures that the expressions `$left` and `$right` are each evaluated only once, *and* that any temporaries created during their evaluation live at least as long as the result bindings `left` and `right`.

An expansion which used `$left` and `$right` multiple times -- once while performing the comparison, and again when interpolating into an error message -- would behave unexpectedly if either expression had side effects. But why can't the expansion do something like `let left = &$left; let right = &$right;`?

Consider:

```
let vals = vec![1, 2, 3, 4].into_iter();
assert_eq!(vals.collect::<Vec<_>>().as_slice(), [1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Suppose this expanded to:

```
let left = &vals.collect::<Vec<_>>().as_slice();
let right = &[1,2,3,4];
if !(*left == *right) {
    panic!("...");
}
```

In Rust, the lifetime of temporaries produced within a statement is generally limited to the statement itself. Therefore, this expansion [is an error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=6ddf6d18bfd14db40c11ad202f0b6c31):

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:5:21
   |
5  |         let left = &vals.collect::<Vec<_>>().as_slice();
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^           - temporary value dropped here while still borrowed
   |                     |
   |                     temporary value does not live long enough
```

The temporary `vals.collect::<Vec<_>>()` needs to live at least as long as `left`, but in fact it is dropped at the end of the `let` statement.

Contrast this with the expansion

```
match (&vals.collect::<Vec<_>>().as_slice(), &[1,2,3,4]) {
    (left, right) => {
        if !(*left == *right) {
            panic!("...");
        }
    }
}
```

This produces the same temporary, but its lifetime extends over the entire match expression -- long enough for us to compare `left` and `right`, and interpolate them into the error message if the comparison fails.

In this sense, `match` is Rust's `let ... in` construct.

Note that this situation is unchanged with [non-lexical lifetimes](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/edition-guide/rust-2018/ownership-and-lifetimes/non-lexical-lifetimes.html). Despite its name, NLL does not change the lifetime of any values -- i.e. when they are dropped. It only makes the scopes of *borrows* more precise. So it does not help us in this situation.

Comment: What does this answer add to the existing answer, which already states *As you can see, we're calling the function twice.*?

Comment: IMHO, the other answer is essentially incorrect, or at least leaves out the _main_ reason to use `match`. Avoiding double evaluation could be done with `let left = $left; let right = $right;` The essence of the OP's question, I believe, is: why doesn't that work?

Comment: I'll second that sentiment. I was left confused about why `match` was used over `let` after reading the other answer; this answer does a nice job of walking through the explanation that's alluded to in the comment thread on the other answer. Thank you for writing it up, @John! (The first comment is rather accusatory, so I wanted to leave you some words of encouragement. It's really useful to have both answers!)

Comment: Same feeling. The accepted answer only explains why `match` works, not why it is necessary, as the question asks. This should probably be the accepted answer.