# Creating a Custom Colored dbg! Macro In Rust

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'd like to create a custom macro similar to the standard [dbg! macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/hello/print/print_debug.html), but with the option to use colors via the [colored](https://crates.io/crates/colored) crate. dbg! usually prints something with the format of

```
[path_to_file:line_number] "symbol name" = "symbol value"
//[src/gallery/image_slot.rs:231] "my_integer_value_of_12" = "12"
```

1. How do I access the path/line number `[path_to_file:line_number]` so I can print it?
2. How do I access the symbol name of a variable? (i.e. print `my_var` given `my_var = 12`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Use the [`file!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.file.html), [`line!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.line.html), and [`column!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.column.html) macros.
2. Use the [`stringify!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.stringify.html) macro.

If you go to the docs of the [`dbg!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.dbg.html) macro, you can click [[src]](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/macros.rs.html#283-301), which shows the implementation of `dbg!`, which is as follows:

```rust
macro_rules! dbg {
    () => {
        $crate::eprintln!("[{}:{}]", $crate::file!(), $crate::line!());
    };
    ($val:expr $(,)?) => {
        // Use of `match` here is intentional because it affects the lifetimes
        // of temporaries - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48732525/1063961
        match $val {
            tmp => {
                $crate::eprintln!("[{}:{}] {} = {:#?}",
                    $crate::file!(), $crate::line!(), $crate::stringify!($val), &tmp);
                tmp
            }
        }
    };
    ($($val:expr),+ $(,)?) => {
        ($($crate::dbg!($val)),+,)
    };
}
```

---

Using that, we can easily create a similar `colored_dbg!` macro, with the [`colored` crate](https://crates.io/crates/colored) as you suggested.

*(I just picked random colors, for a simple example)*

```
// colored = "2.0"
use colored::Colorize;

macro_rules! colored_dbg {
    () => {
        eprintln!("{}", format!("[{}:{}]", file!(), line!()).green());
    };
    ($val:expr $(,)?) => {
        match $val {
            tmp => {
                eprintln!("{} {} = {}",
                    format!("[{}:{}]", file!(), line!()).green(),
                    stringify!($val).red(),
                    format!("{:#?}", &tmp).blue(),
                );
                tmp
            }
        }
    };
    ($($val:expr),+ $(,)?) => {
        ($(colored_dbg!($val)),+,)
    };
}
```

You'd use it just like how you'd be able to use `dbg!`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let my_var = 12;
    colored_dbg!(&my_var);

    let v = vec!["foo", "bar", "baz"];
    let v = colored_dbg!(v);
}
```

Which outputs the following:

[image: screenshot]