# How can I redirect dbg!() to stdout?

Tags: debugging, rust

There are some situations where stderr is not available. Is there a way to have `dbg!()` print to stdout or an alternative command that prints the same information as `dbg!()` to stdout?

Comment: you cannot redirect. You would need to use something else.

Comment: Could you clarify what your use case is? Would running the binary with a shell redirect like `2>&1` work for you?

Comment: if `stderr` is not available you could always redirect it at the shell level with `2>&1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an alternative command, copy-and-paste the [implementation of `dbg`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.58.1/library/std/src/macros.rs#L286-L308), changing `eprintln` to `println` and `$crate` to `::std`:

```rust
macro_rules! dbg {
    // NOTE: We cannot use `concat!` to make a static string as a format argument
    // of `println!` because `file!` could contain a `{` or
    // `$val` expression could be a block (`{ .. }`), in which case the `println!`
    // will be malformed.
    () => {
        ::std::println!("[{}:{}]", ::std::file!(), ::std::line!())
    };
    ($val:expr $(,)?) => {
        // Use of `match` here is intentional because it affects the lifetimes
        // of temporaries - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48732525/1063961
        match $val {
            tmp => {
                ::std::println!("[{}:{}] {} = {:#?}",
                    ::std::file!(), ::std::line!(), ::std::stringify!($val), &tmp);
                tmp
            }
        }
    };
    ($($val:expr),+ $(,)?) => {
        ($(::std::dbg!($val)),+,)
    };
}

fn main() {
    dbg!(1 + 1);
}
```