# Is it possible to get the name of a struct using one of its methods?

Tags: reflection, types, rust

For example:

```
struct ABC;

impl ABC {
    fn some_method(&self) -> &str {
        // return the name of its struct -> "ABC"
    }
}
```

I'm writing Python extensions and I need a way to return the current struct's name for its `repr` method. In Python, I can get this using `self.__class__.__name__`. Is there anything similar in Rust?

Comment: See specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29168659/155423).

Comment: @Shepmaster I'm writing Python extenstions and I needed a way to return the current struct's name for its `__repr__` method

Comment: You are already familiar with [PyO3](https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3), I assume? I would have thought they had tools to do this for you.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm using. Is this kind of "introspection" not encouraged in Rust?

Comment: I wouldn't say discouraged, just uncommon. The `Debug` macro does the same thing, really, and uses stable Rust. That's why I'd expect the PyO3 to have a solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's possible with nightly and the `core_intrinsics` feature:

```
#![feature(core_intrinsics)]

use std::intrinsics::type_name;

struct ABC;

impl ABC {
    fn some_method(&self) -> &'static str {
        unsafe { type_name::<Self>() }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", ABC.some_method()); // ABC
}
```