# Why do I not get a literal out of range error when storing a number larger than an i32 into a variable?

Tags: types, rust, literals

The Rust documentation says the default integer type is `i32`, which means the biggest number a variable can save by default is `2147483647` i.e `2e31 - 1` . This turned out to be true too: if I try to save greater number than `2e31 - 1` in the `x` variable, I get the error `literal out of range`.

**Code**

```
fn main() {
    let x = 2147483647;
    println!("Maximum signed integer: {}", x);
    let x = 2e100;
    println!("x evalues to: {}", x);
}
```

but why do I not get error if I save value `2e100` in the `x` variable? It surely evaluates to greater than `2e31 - 1`.

**Output**

```
Maximum signed integer: 2147483647
x evalues to: 20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

**Code**

```
fn main() {
    let x = 2147483648;
    println!("Maximum signed integer: {}", x);
}
```

**Output**

```
error: literal out of range for i32
 --> src/main.rs:2:11
  |
2 |     let x=2147483648;
  |           ^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: #[deny(overflowing_literals)] on by default
```

Comment: Careful with your notations: `2e31` is 2 × 10^31 = , not 2^31. `2e31 - 1` is 19999999999999999999999999999999 (modulo rounding error).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Constant literals such as `2e100` are not integer literals but floating point literals. This can be shown with

```rust
fn main() {
    let () = 2e100;
}
```

which produces

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:2:9
  |
2 |     let () = 2e100;
  |         ^^ expected floating-point number, found ()
  |
  = note: expected type `{float}`
             found type `()`
```

See also:

- [How do I print the type of a variable in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21747136/how-do-i-print-the-type-of-a-variable-in-rust)