# How to determine the resulting type of a Rust iterator?

Tags: rust

I am working through the [rustlings](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings) exercises to learn Rust. I have reached the [iterator3.rs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings/blob/master/exercises/standard_library_types/iterator3.rs) exercise and am stuck. This exercise asks me to provide a line of code that will map results from one type to another as part of the operation; I need to fill in the line x= with the correct operation. There are two parts - the first reads in part:

```
let numbers = vec![27, 297, 38502, 81];
let division_results = numbers.into_iter().map(|n| divide(n, 27));
let x = ???
assert_eq!(format!("{:?}", x), "Ok([1, 11, 1426, 3])");
```

The next is the same with a slightly different format for the assertion of the output:

```
assert_eq!(format!("{:?}", x), "[Ok(1), Ok(11), Ok(1426), Ok(3)]");
```

I believe I understand that the first instance needs to return a Result that contains either a Vector of i32 or some error type. The second needs to return a Vector of Results that each have a i32  or an error type.

I am, however, generally having difficulty understanding how to determine what type is returned by the combinations of into_iter, map, and collect. I could use some help in learning how to reason about it or in getting compiler assistance.

Here is where I am so far:

I don't understand what the resultant type of division_results is. I have tried to use compiler error messages as well as [the answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21747136/how-do-i-print-the-type-of-a-variable-in-rust/29168659#29168659) to find out, but the results are opaque to me, perhaps because of lazy evaluation. For example, just replacing x with division_results so that assert will show the types, like this:

```
assert_eq!(format!("{:?}", division_results), "Ok([1, 11, 1426, 3])");
```

Gives me this result:

```
left: `"Map { iter: IntoIter([27, 297, 38502, 81]) }"`,
right: `"Ok([1, 11, 1426, 3])"`', exercises/standard_library_types/iterator3.rs:75:9
```

And it isn't clear what the left side results are as the iteration and map have not happened. The other various things I have tried provide similar results.

Thinking that the problem is lazy evaluation, I have also tried using collect to see if that will force evaluation. For example, calling collect at the end of the division_results line like this:

```
division_results = numbers.into_iter().map(|n| divide(n, 27)).collect();
```

Provides an error:

```
cannot infer type consider giving `division_results` a type
```

When I modify collect to say:

```
let division_results = numbers.into_iter().map(|n| divide(n, 27)).collect::<i32>();
```

I get an error that I thought gave me a hint at the right type:

```
let division_results = numbers.into_iter().map(|n| divide(n, 27)).collect::<i32>();
   |                                                                           ^^^^^^^ a collection of type `i32` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=std::result::Result<i32, DivisionError>>`
```

So I tried with the type shown in the error message:

```
let division_results = numbers.into_iter().map(|n| divide(n, 27)).collect::<Result<i32, DivisionError>>();
```

Only to get this error:

```
let division_results = numbers.into_iter().map(|n| divide(n, 27)).collect::<Result<i32, DivisionError>>();
   |                                                                           ^^^^^^^ a collection of type `i32` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=i32>`
```

Clearly I am missing something. Perhaps you can tell me what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `map()` method on an *iterator adapter*; it takes an iterator, and returns another iterator, but it does not consume any items from the original iterator by itself. The return type `Map` is a wrapper around the original iterator that applies the provided closure to every item when they are consumed.

If you want the `Map` to actually do something, you need to *consume* the iterator. The most common ways to do so are `for` loops and the `collect()` method (but there are many other methods that consume the iterator, like `sum()`, `count()`, `fold()`, `max()`, …). In this particular case, calling the `collect()` method is most appropriate, since you want to collect the results in a vector.

You already figured out that the desired type for `x` is a `Result` wrapping a vector of `i32` or an error, or `Result<Vec<i32>, DivisionError>` in Rust syntax. Since `collect()` can produce many different return types, we need to tell the compiler which one we want. One way to do so is to explicitly specify the type of `x`:

```
let x: Result<Vec<i32>, DivisionError> = division_results.collect();
```

This uses an [implementation of the `FromIterator` trait that allows to collect an iterable of `Result`s into a `Result` wrapping a collection of values](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html#impl-FromIterator%3CResult%3CA%2C%20E%3E%3E).

The other case you mentioned is very similar. This time, the target type is a vector of `Result` instances, so all you need to do is specify the different type. This will automatically select the right implementation of `FromIterator` for you:

```
let x: Vec<Result<i32, DivisionError>> = division_results.collect();
```

Comment: Thanks! I am more used to C and keep underestimating how much Rust will do for me. I'll try these out.