# Does Rust implicitly convert direct slices to references of slices?

Tags: rust

For example, are these the same, or does doing `let x = myar[2]` clone the number 3 and put it in `x`?

```
let myar = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let x = myar[2];
```

```
let x = &myar[2];
```

Comment: There are no slices in this code. There's no term "direct slice" in Rust, either.

Comment: You may be interested in [How do I print the type of a variable in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21747136/155423).

Comment: `myar[2]` is plain array access, not a slice, `let x = myar[2]` copies `3` into a new variable `x`, what would you expect?

Answer (score 3):

**No.**

`let x = myar[2];` does indeed copy the value `3` and store it in `x`, while `let x = &myar[2];` stores a reference to the value `3` in `myar`.

Note that the only reason `let x = myar[2];` works at all is because `i32` implements the `Copy` trait. If we had an array storing a type that does not implement the `Copy` trait, you wouldn't be able to do that at all. For example:

```
struct Number {
    num: i32,
}

impl Number {
    fn new(num: i32) -> Number {
        Number { num }
    }
}
// Note that Number does not implement the Copy trait

fn main() {
    let number_list = [Number::new(1), Number::new(2), Number::new(3)];

    // This does not work:
    let _x = number_list[1];

    // This does work:
    let _x = &number_list[1];
}
```