# Websocket JSON parsing type mismatch

Tags: json, websocket, rust, serde

I'm trying to hack together a simple WebSocket client using tungstenite that parses JSON. Most of the code comes from [this example](https://github.com/snapview/tungstenite-rs/blob/bbaa48b4d6cbc551232f27f00bdc5cc32df78525/examples/client.rs).

If I do `println!("{}", msg)` It works fine, so I'm not sure why the type is mismatched (`msg` is supposedly a string right?). https://docs.rs/tungstenite/0.6.1/tungstenite/protocol/enum.Message.html

```
use tungstenite::{connect};
use url::Url;
use serde_json;

fn main() {

    let (mut socket, _response) =
        connect(Url::parse("wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime?subscribe=trade:XBTUSD").unwrap()).expect("Can't connect");

    loop {
        let msg = socket.read_message().expect("Error reading message");
        let parsed: serde_json::Value = serde_json::from_str(&msg).expect("Can't parse to JSON");
        println!("{:?}", parsed["data"][0]["price"]);
    }

}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:12:62
   |
12 |         let parsed: serde_json::Value = serde_json::from_str(&msg).expect("Can't parse to JSON");
   |                                                              ^^^^ expected `str`, found enum `tungstenite::protocol::message::Message`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&str`
              found reference `&tungstenite::protocol::message::Message`
```

```
[dependencies]
tungstenite = "0.10.1"
url = "2.1.1"
serde_json = "1.0.53"
```

Comment: *msg is supposedly a string* — [How do I print the type of a variable in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21747136/155423)

Comment: You can `println!("{}", msg)` because [`tungstenite::Message`](https://docs.rs/tungstenite/0.10.1/tungstenite/enum.Message.html) implements `Display`. See the documentation on how to turn it into a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```rust
use tungstenite::{connect};
use url::Url;
use serde_json;

fn main() {

    let (mut socket, _response) =
        connect(Url::parse("wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime?subscribe=trade:XBTUSD").unwrap()).expect("Can't connect");

    loop {
        let msg = socket.read_message().expect("Error reading message");
        let msg = match msg {
            tungstenite::Message::Text(s) => { s }
            _ => { panic!() }
        };
        let parsed: serde_json::Value = serde_json::from_str(&msg).expect("Can't parse to JSON");
        println!("{:?}", parsed["data"][0]["price"]);
    }

}
```

Comment: That works! I tried using to_text() / into_text() from here https://docs.rs/tungstenite/0.6.1/tungstenite/protocol/enum.Message.html any idea why that doesnt work? Anyways thanks!