# What does it mean to call a generic function with a tuple struct's type as the parameter?

Tags: generics, rust

This code compile and run without problem

```
struct A(i32);

fn ooo<T>(_t: T) {}

fn main() {
    ooo(A);
}
```

I don't understand

- the meaning of `ooo(A)`
- the type of `_t`

Comment: `A` is a function that accepts an `i32` and returns an `A`. All functions are their own type, but that type can become a function pointer or implement the `Fn*` traits.

Comment: See also [How do I print the type of a variable in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21747136/155423): `let _: () = A;` => *found fn item `fn(i32) -> A {A}`*