# How to find out the type of an enum element?

Tags: rust

So, I basically have an `enum` and a `struct`:

```rust
enum tonsTypes
{
    TotalSum(String),
    Batches(Vec<String>)
}

struct Duo
{
    name:String,
    tons: tonsTypes
}
```

Then, I have a `du = Vec<Duo>` where `Duo.tons` can be either `String` or `Vec<String>`. Is there any way of finding out what each duo[i].tons is? Is it a `String` or a `Vec<String>`?

I want to do something like:

```
 for x in duo
    if (//if x.tons is of type String)
    then do this ...
    else //(if it is of type Vec<String>)
    then do this..
```

.

Thank you!

Comment: map and with an if let Batches(s) =x or match inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```rust
enum tonsTypes
{
    TotalSum(String),
    Batches(Vec<String>)
}

struct Duo
{
    name:String,
    tons: tonsTypes
}

fn main() {
    let duos = vec![
        Duo{
            name: "Test1".to_string(),
            tons: tonsTypes::TotalSum("TotalSum".to_string())
        },
        Duo{
            name: "Test2".to_string(),
            tons: tonsTypes::Batches(vec!["Batch1".to_string(), "Batch2".to_string()])
        }
    ];
    
    let mut iter = duos.iter();
    match_value(&iter.next().unwrap().tons);
    match_value(&iter.next().unwrap().tons);
}

fn match_value(value: &tonsTypes){
    match value {
        tonsTypes::TotalSum(value) => print_type_of(value),
        tonsTypes::Batches(value) => print_type_of(value),
    }
}

fn print_type_of<T>(_: &T) {
    println!("{}", std::any::type_name::<T>())
}
```

Playground [link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c8810f848b730ef3674ef5915252b202).

However Rust does not really provide a way to retrieve the type and this should not be depended on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58119924/4593433

If you only want to use the type of the enum value for checking something it is better to simply check for that value, because you already know the assigned data type then.
So basically do this instead:

```rust
for x in duo
    if (x.tons == tonsTypes::TotalSum)
        //then do this ...
    else (x.tons == tonsTypes::Batches)
        //then do this..
```