# do rust type annotations affect speed, or are used just for readability's sake

Tags: rust

I'm learning rust and I have this question.

Is this

```
let x: i32 = 1;
```

Faster than

```
let x = 1;
```

Or is it just for readability?

Comment: Neither, actually.

Comment: The generated code will be exactly the same for both.

Comment: Look at the assembly output. Unless you guessed something strange, like `i8`, the code will likely be identical.

Answer (score 4):

You can investigate a compiled Rust program (that is, what the Rust compiler produces from Rust source code) easily using a tool such as [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/).

See the following example: https://godbolt.org/z/54x3Gd9oo

[image: Godbolt compiler Rust image]

As you can see, the compiled output is identical (as far as the arithmetic is concerned, the fact that the two functions are named differently introduces some minor differences). From this, you can infer that there is no speed advantage, and that the Rust compiler erases these details at compile time. It cannot have any effect on the wall time of the program being run, but as @Christina Sørensen says, it may affect compile time.

Comment: This is probably not the best example because, as you can see, the variable is optimised out completely — the value resides directly in a register. So this doesn’t really tell us whether the compiler would still generate the same code in situations where the variable was represented by an addressable memory location in code (but of course it does).

Comment: Good point, edited to include a more correct example.

Answer (score 1):

We can test this by printing the type, inspired by this answer:
[How do I print in Rust the type of a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21747136/how-do-i-print-in-rust-the-type-of-a-variable)

```rust
fn print_type_of<T>(_: &T) {
    println!("{}", std::any::type_name::<T>())
}


fn main() {
    let x: i32 = 1;
    let y = 1;
    print_type_of(&x);
    print_type_of(&y);
}
```

Which will print out:

```
i32
i32
```

What happens when we don't explicitly tell rust what type to use is that rust will try to infer it.

As we can see here, the compiler on my computer made the variables the same type, but it's important to know that this is not a guarantee.

As to whether or not it's faster, usually, being explicit about what type you want the variable to be means that the compiler has to do less thinking, making the program faster to compile. The same holds for interpreted languages, where the program will have a faster runtime, because again it does not need to think about what kind of type to give the variable.

However, it's not a very large difference, and when it has been decided it's unlikely to have an impact on runtime.

Comment: No, this is *not* called dynamic type checking. Dynamic type checking is very different (it happens at runtime). Rust uses static type checking in both cases, it just *infers* the type in one case.